# Microsoft Access Dsum Single Criteria Not Working

Tags: ms-access, criteria

i am working on Access project. Dsum is working fine without Criteria but when i insert criteria. it simply not working.

```
 Me.usd = DSum("[Amount]", "Commission", "Currency= usd")
```

"me.usd" is TextBox And 
"Amount" is column and "
Commission" is Table
"Currency" is where to look for currency type

if i exclude criteria with "" it gives total amount sum but it returns nothing with criteria. can anyone correct where i am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings should be enclosed with single quotes in where clause

```vb
Me.usd = DSum("[Amount]", "Commission", "[Currency]= 'usd'")
```

If the currency field is number use below, no need for quotes. Assuming USD = 1 in your case

```vb
Me.usd = DSum("[Amount]", "Commission", "[Currency]= 1")
```

Comment: Try it `?DSum("[Amount]", "Commission", "[Currency]= 'usd'")` in immediate window and see what the results.

Comment: Do the currency USD have unwanted spaces around? check in your table.

Comment: run-time error 3464 data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Comment: Is currency number or string? What does it appear in the table for field currency?

Comment: one-thing the currency is drop-down linked with other table.

Comment: What the value of USD in lookup table?

Comment: in table is shown as number (field type) and value is USD, Euro, GBP

Comment: `Me.usd = DSum("[Amount]", "Commission", "[Currency]= 1")` replace 1 with usd value from other table.

Comment: it worked great hats-off to you. i didn't checked the data type. you really did resolve my problem.